# ControllerActivator creating a different controller type than requested

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a custom controller activator, and I am wanting to create a different controller to the one asked for.  This code worked in .net framework, but in .net core, I'm getting a cast error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[] arguments)
```

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
```

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
```

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

In my custom activator, I always return the TestController, regardless of what's asked for.  I overwrit the actiondescriptor and method info for the action I want.

```
 public object Create(ControllerContext context)
 {
     // Always return the TestController, 
     var controller = new TestController();

     MethodInfo method = controller.GetType().GetMethod(context.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.Name);

     context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName = "Test";
     context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName = context.ActionDescriptor.DisplayName.Replace("HomeController", "TestController");
     context.ActionDescriptor.ControllerTypeInfo = typeof(TestController).GetTypeInfo();
     context.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo = method;
     controller.ControllerContext = context;

     return controller;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get around this check after a few days of experimenting.

Instead, I wrote some middleware that is invoked earlier in the pipeline stage to change the url to the controller requested.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).